# gmail api oauth two accounts possible issue

Tags: gmail-api

I have been working on a grails demo site which covers various methods of using gmail api mail plugin to send emails using standard,multiple To recipients, html emails, inline image(s). 
As well as a method to override or use different gmail accounts. This can all be found [here](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/gmail-api-test)

Whilst doing the tests I noticed a strange behaviour with oauth, it is explained on the bottom of the README on that provided link

> Unsure about this bit a little confusing as to how it works. lets say
>   I generated client_secret.json under gmail account username Bob When
>   for the very first email that needs to be confirmed via this site on a
>   given account a one off process. During that 1 off process if i log in
>   to gmail with another account of Bill The key is verified and emails
>   then appear to come from bill@gmail.com Even though I had not visited
>   / configured Bill's account to use the client_secret.json file.

So in short if I generate a secret.json file from account1, when sending the very first email from that account. If I happen to be logged in from account2. The storedCredentials file generated by google (there on) the `'me'` account becomes my 2nd account. Even though everything to generate the key etc was done on account1.

Does it make sense is this normal behaviour or a bug ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a bug or not. If you think this is a bug, then you can file a [bug report](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?labels=Type-Defect,API-Gmail) for it. And if you file a bug report about it, can you please include the link of the bug in this question. So other people in this community know how to handle this event if they experienced this. Thanks

Comment: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5222&thanks=5222&ts=1489156652 @KENdi thanks logged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `client_secret.json` file only needs to be generated once per application. It is how the application identifies itself to Google, and generating it does not grant any API access to any accounts. The same client secrets file is used to perform the OAuth flow for all the users that want to grant the application access to their data.

Comment: Thanks Eric, unsure maybe I haven't explained it properly. `client_secret.json` generated for application created under `usera`. When application is started for the very first time the developer is provided with a link to verify the app key. If at this point developer is logged in with another gmail account. Specifically an account that was not used to access developer console and generate app key etc - the emails sent from there on would be from that user. In the provided github example. I altered behaviour so that it would connect to multiple accounts. Noticed this issue whilst alternating

Comment: The behavior you explained is correct. It doesn't matter who created the `client_secret.json` file or who owns that developer project. Any user can authorize access with the same secret file, and the token generated as a result will always be bound to the user that clicked "Authorize".

Comment: Thanks Eric. I had feedback on actual issue raised and it pretty much said the same thing as you are saying now. The behaviour appeared odd hence my question hopefully might help others if they spot same behaviour and scratch their heads for a while